# Modifying hash-tables in Common Lisp and Let

Tags: lisp, hashtable, common-lisp, evaluation

I've been trying to modify a hash-table with the following code

```
(let ((alist '(gethash key *hash-table*)))
  (setf alist (cons 'key 'weight)))
```

but the problem is that it doesn't actually modify the hash-table (also note that

```
(let ((alist (gethash key *hash-table*)))
  (setf alist (cons 'key 'weight)))
```

doesn't work either, while the following code does work.

```
(setf (gethash key *hash-table*) (cons 'key 'weight)))
```

I can't understand why this works and the other one doesn't work. This is useful (outside of this code snippet) because (I assume) this is why I can't run a function  like

```
(alist-initialize (gethash key *hash-table*))
```

with the definition being:

```
(defun alist-initialize (alist)
  (setf alist (cons 'a 'b))
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Setting a variable modifies its local binding.
You would not expect

```
(let ((a 5))
  (setf a 2))
```

to somehow change the value of `5` to `2`.
Similarly,

```
(let ((alist (gethash key *hash-table*))) 
  (setf alist (cons 'key 'weight)))
```

has no effect on `(gethash key *hash-table*)`.
What happens there is that `key` it looked up in `*hash-table*` and `alist` is bound to the value returned. Then [`setf`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_setf_.htm) modifies the binding of `alist`, being completely oblivious to the previous binding.

(note that your first form quotes the [`gethash`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_gethas.htm) call and thus does not access the hash table at all).

Your function should be defined like this:

```
(defun alist-initialize (key alist)
  (setf (gethash key *hash-table*) alist))
```

and called with *two* arguments, not *one*.

"In the interest of full disclosure", CL does provide facilities to go what you want (see [`symbol-macrolet`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/s_symbol.htm) and [`define-symbol-macro`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_defi_1.htm)) but this is relatively advanced material which you should, IMO, ignore for now.

Answer (score 1):

Why would you mix an assoc list and a hash-table? Both can be used for similar purposes, but they are independent of each other.

If you want to put something into a hash-table you have to write:

```
(setf (gethash key *hash-table*) value)
```

If you want to get the value:

```
(gethash key *hash-table*)
```